# SQL Before Trigger Not Working

Tags: oracle, plsql, triggers

I am learning oracle and trying to implement a before trigger. I think i have the code correct but once I run an insert statement the trigger does not get called or used, but the row is still inserted into the table. Can any one see what I am doing wrong or know why the trigger isnt working?

This is the trigger I am using

```
create or replace
TRIGGER DAY_CHECK BEFORE
  INSERT ON AD_SLOT FOR EACH ROW DECLARE p_day AD_SLOT.DAY_OF_WEEK%TYPE;
  NOTVALID EXCEPTION;
  BEGIN
    IF p_day IN ('Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday', 'Sunday') THEN
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('VALID DAY');
    ELSE
      RAISE NOTVALID;
    END IF;
 EXCEPTION
 WHEN NOTVALID THEN
   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('NOT A VALID DAY');
   RAISE;
 END;
```

this is the insert statement that I am testing with, It should be raising the exception as the day is not valid

```
 insert into ad_slot values (78955, 'testday', 'ER', 'House', 'Taken', 7654321, '05=FEB-2014 21:00:00');
```

Test Case used

```
INSERT INTO ad_slot (DAY_OF_WEEK) VALUES ('unwanted day');
```

Comment: You never assign a value to `p_day`. Plus you cannot use `commit` or rollback` in a trigger.

Comment: How would I assign it to the value that the user has entered?

Comment: or would something like 'select day_of_week into p_day from ad_slot' work?

Comment: You can access the row that is affected by the trigger using `new`. This is all documented in the manual: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/triggers.htm#LNPLS020

Comment: No need to use keyword `new` anymore.

Comment: @Hayes121, your update is nowhere close to my suggested code.

Comment: My edit is using the very same code you have given, but like i said the trigger is being ignored

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to put `RAISE` in the `EXCEPTION` block to not let the `INSERT` work for unwanted week days. Else, the row would be inserted anyway.

```
SQL> CREATE TABLE ad_slot(day_of_week VARCHAR2(20));

Table created.

SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER DAY_CHECK BEFORE
  2    INSERT ON AD_SLOT FOR EACH ROW DECLARE p_day AD_SLOT.DAY_OF_WEEK%TYPE;
  3    NOTVALID EXCEPTION;
  4    BEGIN
  5      IF p_day IN ('Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday', 'Sunday') THEN
  6        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('VALID DAY');
  7      ELSE
  8        RAISE NOTVALID;
  9      END IF;
 10    EXCEPTION
 11    WHEN NOTVALID THEN
 12      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('NOT A VALID DAY');
 13      RAISE;
 14    END;
 15  /

Trigger created.

SQL>
SQL> INSERT INTO ad_slot VALUES ('unwanted day');
NOT A VALID DAY
INSERT INTO ad_slot VALUES ('unwanted day')
            *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-06510: PL/SQL: unhandled user-defined exception
ORA-06512: at "LALIT.DAY_CHECK", line 12
ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'LALIT.DAY_CHECK'


SQL>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply lalit, but when i tried running this code i got the error 'ORA-06512: at "DT2113A.DAY_CHECK", line 11
ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'DT2113A.DAY_CHECK''

Comment: Error starting at line 254 in command:
insert into ad_slot values (78955, 'Monday', 'ER', 'House', 'Taken', 7654321, '05=FEB-2014 21:00:00')
Error report:
SQL Error: ORA-20001: Program duration is not long enough
ORA-06512: at "DT2113A.DAY_CHECK", line 11
ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'DT2113A.DAY_CHECK'

Comment: There is no change to your trigger, just removed commit and tollback and added RAISE in exception block.  Did you try with a single insert as I did?

Comment: yes i tried the insert that you suggested but that just inserted the value and the trigger didnt stop it

Comment: Impossible, if you see my answer, the `RAISE` will stop the row from being inserted due to unhandled exception thrown in your trigger code. I have given you a test case which should work. Can you copy paste the way I did in my answer. Use SQL*Plus to post your test case, edit your question and paste it.

Comment: i have the code the very same as your code and using the exact same test case but it is still just ignoring the trigger

Comment: You need to post a test case to SHOW the way I did. It would just take 5 minutes to copy paste.

Comment: Look at your update properly, and compare it with my code. You didn't exactly do what I suggested. You still have the commit and rollback, and the worst part is you still do not have RAISE in your exception block.